# How do I balance surface area and volume in my outdoor fish pond?

Tags: health, fish, pond

I have three outdoor fish pot ponds. They are taller then they are wide. Now this mean the surface area meeting the atmosphere is quite small compared to the volume.

I was under the impression, that it's the surface of the pond that helps to bring oxygen into the water. I could be totally mistaken about this.

I am wondering if there is any information about pond depth and the surface area exposed to the atmosphere and the environment health, in such, as being optimal for fish.

*Please this is not a question about artificial filtration, it is about possible exchanges made at the surface of the pond and any possible natural conventions created within the pond.*

Comment: Please do not go into the pros and cons of my set up.. At almost every post I have made about my fish, I get comments about having man-made filtration.

Comment: I don't know enough about pond systems to give a full answer, but you want to consider both the surface area of the air/water boundary and how well both are circulating. Really deep systems can have problems getting enough oxygen to the bottom of the water column if there's not enough mixing going on.

Answer (score 4):

I found this professor's explanation about what atfects oxygenation in ponds:http://www2.ca.uky.edu/wkrec/lowoxygenandpondaeration.htm

Surprisingly, it suggests to me that the total depth matters more than the surface/volume ratio. In particular, ponds over 8 ft. deep can lose oxygen at lower levels in hot water.

Comment: If you're interested I posted this http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-role-does-algae-play-in-healthy-pond-life